# Apache POI - Negative color values

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to write a code that outputs the color of cells in an Excel sheet, but when calling the method GetFillBackgroundColor, it gives me back three negative values. I'm wondering, are there somehow related to the RGB numbers?
This is the code I wrote:

```
CellStyle style = currentCell2.getCellStyle();
Color color = style.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
if (color != null) {
    byte[] clr = ((XSSFColor) color).getRGB();
    System.out.print("( ");
    for (int k = 0; k<clr.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(clr[k]+" ");
    } 
    System.out.print(" )");
}
```

[A picture of the Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcIcc.png)

Comment: can you give us the color you used to test it?

Comment: I added a picture of the excel file I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

A `byte` is always signed in Java. You may get its unsigned value by doing a binary `AND` with `0xFF`:

```
...
System.out.print((clr[k] & 0xFF) + " ");
...
```

But if you do `Color color = style.getFillBackgroundColorColor();` you will get only **one** possible fill color out of two.

`Excel` cells may have pattern filling and then the `FillBackgroundColorColor` is the color behind the pattern and the `FillForegroundColorColor` is the color of the pattern. But default fully filled cells have solid pattern and so you need the `FillForegroundColorColor` because the `FillBackgroundColorColor` is fully covered by the pattern.

So I believe you will need `Color color = style.getFillForegroundColorColor();`.

Comment: Thank you! That works in converting the numbers in positive ones. But I tested some of the numbers with RGB and they convert to the wrong colors. For instance I have a blue color, but according to its numbers should be a dark grey. Do you know why it's happening?